# PHP PDO succinct mySQL SELECT object

Tags: mysql, function, object, pdo

Using PDO I have built a succinct object for retrieving rows from a database as a PHP object with the first column value being the name and the second column value being the desired value.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `site`"; $site = array();
foreach($sodb->query($sql) as $sitefield){
    $site[$sitefield['name']] = $sitefield['value'];
}
```

I now want to apply it to a function with 2 parameters, the first containing the table and the second containing any where clauses to then produce the same result.

```
function select($table,$condition){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `$table`";
    if($condition){
        $sql .= " WHERE $condition";
    }
    foreach($sodb->query($sql) as $field){
        return $table[$field['name']] = $field['value'];
    }
}
```

The idea that this could be called something like this:

```
 <?php select("options","class = 'apples'");?>
```

and then be used on page in the same format as the first method.

```
<?php echo $option['green'];?>
```

Giving me the value of the column named value that is in the same row as the value called 'green' in the column named field.

The problem of course is that the function will not return the foreach data like that. That is that this bit:

```
        foreach($sodb->query($sql) as $field){
            return $table[$field['name']] = $field['value'];
        }
```

cannot return data like that.

Is there a way to make it?

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? I find it a bit hard to follow what you are trying to accomplish. Could you elaborate?

Comment: a PHP object for whatever table I fancy (hence the function) that gives me an object where I can use rows from one column to call values of their corresponding column. That is, if one column is called 'field' and the other 'value' I want to be able to call a value from that table by its field value. Say echo $site['green'] would look for the row with green as the value in the field column and return me the value in the value column of that row. To do this I want to get an object of all field column rows and call them by the row value of that column name

Answer (score 0):

Well, this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `site`"; $site = array();
foreach($sodb->query($sql) as $sitefield){
    $site[$sitefield['name']] = $sitefield['value'];
}
```

Can easily become this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `site`";
$site = array();
foreach( $sodb->query($sql) as $row )
{
    $site[] = $row;
}

print_r($site);

// or, where 0 is the index you want, etc.
echo $site[0]['name'];
```

So, you should be able to get a map of all of your columns into the multidimensional array `$site`.

Also, don't forget to sanitize your inputs before you dump them right into that query. One of the benefits of PDO is using placeholders to protect yourself from malicious users.

Comment: @PeeHaa: Which is why I noted that OP should use PDO placeholders, as opposed to a concatenated string as he is now. I meant to imply that they need to either sanitize, or use PDO properly, with bound params.

Comment: Interesting approach, but a) won't that print even outside the function when the function is listed rather than when the function is called. (maybe not). b) good point on sanitisation. Will test tomorrow and get back to you. Thanks.